# Check String for values other than those allowed. Java

Tags: java, string, match, matching, conditional-statements

I wrote a program that asks the use to input a string of 3 characters, which could be a combination of [a, b, v, ^];

Here's what I have so far:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a two variable logical expression, no spaces: ");    // 'v' for or, '^' for and.
    expression = type.nextLine();
}
while ((expression.length() != 3) || !((expression.toUpperCase()).matches("[AB^V]")));
```

The loop is only suppose to continue when the string is not 3 characters long, or a character in the string is not allowed.

I entered a test string of: a^b, but the loop just keeps going.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, ^ is one of the four characters that are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regular expression is `[AB^V]+`. Indeed the original expression would only match strings of length 1.

```
((expression.toUpperCase()).matches("[AB^V]+"))
```

`^` does not need to be escaped, since it is between `[` and `]` (i.e. in a character class).

**Edit**: actually `^` should be escaped if it was at the beginning of the character class (like in `[\\^ABV]+`), but not when it is preceded by other characters.

Comment: +1 and this is even simpler version `while (!(expression.toUpperCase().matches("[\\^ABV]{3}")));` or even `while (!(expression.matches("(?i)[\\^ABV]{3}")));` `(?i)` will make regex case-insensitive :)

Comment: Wow that's pretty cryptic, but thanks. I always seek to apply the highest level of efficiency to my code.